# Proxy server with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: proxy, xampp, raspberry-pi

One of my friends has really bad internet and I was wondering if it was possible to turn my Raspberry Pi into a proxy server to help him boost his internet. Is this possible?

If it is possible, how would I go about doing this? Install `xampp`, wipe up some PHP and there ya go, or is it a little more complicated?

Comment: This question would be much better for SO if you actually attempted to create the proxy server, ran into specific problems, and then asked about how to solve those problems (including asking about alternatives).

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) server. It is easier to configure.

You may google for how to set it up.